# Unable to select option using capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am unable to select an option from an html element using capybara

```
   <select multiple="multiple" name="profile_invitation[permissions][]" id="profile_invitation_permissions">
    <option value="manage_permissions">Manage Permissions</option>
    </select>
```

I've tried

```
#within 'select#profile_invitation_permissions' do
    #find("option[@value='manage_permissions']").click
  #end
```

which returns

```
Unable to find css "option[@value='manage_permissions']" within #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="select" path="/html/body/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/form/select"> (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

and I've tried

```
select "Manage Permissions", :from => "select#profile_invitation_permissions"
```

which returns

```
 Unable to find select box "select#profile_invitation_permissions" that is not disabled and Unable to find input box with datalist completion "select#profile_invitation_permissions" that is not disabled (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two `"Manage Permissions"`/`value='manage_permissions'` option tags, and why do you have `@value=` instead of just `value=` in your attribute selector?

Answer (score 1):

You're making it more complicated than it is. From the docs - https://rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#select-instance_method - we can see that `select` takes the text of the option to be selected, and optionally a `from` setting to specify either the id, name, or label of the select box. Therefore if there is only one "Manage Permissions" option on the page you can just do

```
select 'Manage Permissions'
```

If there is more than one matching option on the page then you would narrow it down using the `from` option

```
select 'Manage Permissions', from: 'profile_invitation_permissions'
```